# Lag while typing and scrolling

Tags: lyx

I'm having some trouble with Lyx: once the document reaches a certain length typing and scrolling start to take so long I can actually end doing it and I will see it get done in the screen a couple of seconds later. The last document having this problem has 3012 characters and I'm using equations, title, date and author. My computer is a new Microsoft surface 6 with procesor i7, 16gb ram and 512gb memory running on Windows 10. It runs smoothly on everything else, from surfing at several websites at the same time to performing heavy calculations on Mathematica. My guess is that the problem is arising from some compatibility problem with Lyx. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I think this question belongs here since Lyx runs on Latex. In any case, let me know if you think it is off-topic.

Comment: Well yeah you guessed right. This is unfortunately off topic.

Comment: I see, is there another site where I can ask this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should contact the developers of LyX directly.

Comment: If you have heavy graphics or other includes in tex (lyx or any app) that is having to hit the cpu hard to decode for preview then in tex (lyx preamble) you can usually add draft mode, consider what components are possibly bogging down the main file If you export lyx to latex and run native tex in tex editor (TeXworks usually included in windows MiKTeX) or command line is it also slow.

Comment: What version of LyX are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and turning off "Display graphics" greatly sped things up for me:

Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Display > Uncheck "Display graphics" > Click "Apply", then "OK"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!